# How should comint-derived modes keep track of buffers and processes?

Tags: elisp, programming, comint

Having written a couple of custom `comint`-derived modes, I often find it tricky to decide how to keep track of buffers and processes: for instance, to associate different source buffers with different interpreters.  Is it better to keep a reference to the buffer or the process?

Given a buffer, one can find its associated process using `get-buffer-process`.  Conversely, given a process, `process-buffer` returns its associated buffer.  Both buffers and processes also permit an extra layer of indirection by looking them up by unique name, but this seems fragile compared to just keeping a reference to the object itself.

One possibility seems clearly bad, since it violates the principle of storing data once-and-only-once: namely, keeping references to both the buffer *and* the process.

Most `comint-` functions for sending input take a process rather than a buffer as an argument, which argues for hanging on to the process object, not the buffer.  On the other hand, buffers tend to stick around longer than processes: a process might finish or be killed and a new process started in the buffer it previously used.

Are there other convincing arguments for referencing the process or its buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the reasons you provided, I generally prefer to hold on to the buffer.
Then I write a `foo-proc` function which returns the corresponding process, potentially re-starting it if needed.  And I even sometimes then write a `foo-buffer` function which calls `foo-proc` so that not only it gives me the buffer but it also ensures that the process is running.

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of guidance I was looking for, and I'm not likely to find a better source!